# Software for time based access control of WiFi hotspots

Tags: wifi, access-control, wifi-hotspot

I'm looking for a very simple WiFi hotspot control software which allows internet access to clients for a certain period of time. After the time limit is expired, it blocks access to clients based on MAC address.
The next day the counter will reset, and clients can access again for limited time.
There is no need of any login or account creation, just a simple message like **Time limit expired, Please try again next day** will be sufficient.

It will be better if the software is avail for OpenWrt, already have a TP-Link 1043ND and D-Link DIR-505 running OpenWrt.

Most users are on smartphones, and MAC spoofing is not a big deal.

WiFiDog looks promising, but does it have that capability ?

Though there are some commercial software, but most of them are for power hungry big machines, and expensive too.

Comment: Have you checked to see if you wireless router supports this natively?

Comment: @Centimane, unfortunately I've never checked the default firmware of the TP-Link one, flashed OpenWrt just after receiving, and D-Link one doesn't have any similar functionality.

Comment: You could always check the documentation for the TP-Link one to see if it supports this feature.

Comment: google hits besides wifidog https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.nodogsplash and https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.coova-chilli

Comment: Thanks Rui, I'll experiment with Nodogsplash, it seems to be more lightweight than CoovaChilli.